# podman/Docker container with /var/www/html/ content so i can read from host the test.html file in /var/www/html

Tags: linux, image, docker, containers, podman

i am trying to create a running container and inside that container i want to give a content to test.html which should be in /var/www/html. I should do it by echo command inside the container. Problem is that even after downloading nginx container, i cant find /var/www/html inside the container so lately, when i try to reach for it... i cant of course. I need to use nginx image. I wanted to use httpd container, but i cant, thats why i am asking. Basically i should run the container with command like that

sudo podman run -d --name nginx -p 8180:80 nginx

or

sudo podman run -d --name nginx -p 8180:80 usgs/nginx

Lets imagine i will have /var/www/html in container, i will then do

echo "test text" > /var/www/html/test.html
exit from container
and do curl command in my host terminal
curl 127.0.0.1:8180/test.html
test text

Just to show you, what i need to get.

Comment: You probably want to build a custom Image that `COPY`s in the content you need.  Don't try to edit files in a running container; your changes will be lost as soon as the container exits.

Comment: I FOUND ANSWER! The problem is, that nginx index.html is in /usr/share/nginx/html and nto in /var/www/html, so basically i used the .html files in /usr/share/nginx/html in order to get content from curl 127.0.0.1:8180/test.html. I guess you can close it, guys.

Answer (score -1):

I FOUND ANSWER! The problem is, that nginx index.html is in /usr/share/nginx/html and nto in /var/www/html, so basically i used the .html files in /usr/share/nginx/html in order to get content from curl 127.0.0.1:8180/test.html. I guess you can close it, guys.